# Using PS/2 to USB adapter

Tags: ps2-keyboard

I have the IPISB-CU (Carmel2) motherboard, and as far as I can tell that means it does not include a PS/2 port.  I am wondering, then, if I purchase a USB to PS/2 converter adapter, will a PS/2 keyboard work with Legacy USB support disabled??  I need to do some work in the BIOS.

EDIT:  The chipset is the H61, which when on Intel motherboards DOES have a PS/2 port.  The converse is true for this HP prebuilt desktop that I am working on.  Does anyone know why this is?

Comment: So you have a PS2 keyboard and a motherboard with no PS2 ports, and you want to know if using an adapter will allow you to work in the BIOS?

Comment: Yes, the chipset is the H61, which when on Intel motherboards DOES have a PS/2 port.  The converse is true for this HP prebuilt desktop that I am working on.  Does anyone know why this is?

Comment: There was a time when USB keyboards came with PS/2 adapters, and I used one of these for years as a PS/2 keyboard.

Comment: My experience of former HP computers was that they were always a bit different - HP maybe unable to let go of their hardware manufacturing heritage - so I got used to some degree of quirkiness. I'm sure HP had good reasons for their designs, but it meant that they could have more compatibility problems than more standard designs. They usually needed unique drivers, which could be inconvenient, though the support site was generally good. I've no idea if the same is true today, as I've not used an HP for 10 years.

Comment: Does your adapter work with Windows 10?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that will work. I do that all the time.

But make sure you get the right PS/2 to USB converter.
PS/2 keyboard and PS/2 mouse use the same PS/2 plug, but you need different USB adapters. Some adapters are keyboard only, some are mouse only and some can handle both. Make sure you get the right one.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I have edited my question with a product-specific question.  More so out of curiosity I ask then necessity.  Do you know if this is commonly true of HP designed computers?  Seems rather inane to me, though, not surprising.

Comment: @Abe Shudug PS/2 is old. To the BIOS your keyboard will now look like a USB keyboard. Not sure if you want to work with keyboard scan codes, but things might be different for USB.

Comment: I am interested in the functionality of the PS/2 controller and sending interrupts to different pins.